# How select full children records from linklist

Tags: orientdb

I adds linked document to another like this (ok):

```
create class Doc
create class ParentDoc 
create property ParentDoc.children LINKLIST


insert into Doc set name = 'doc1'                               #12:0
insert into Doc set name = 'doc2'                               #12:1
insert into ParentDoc set name = 'pd', children = [#12:0]       #13:0
update #13:0 add children = #12:1
```

Now I want select all children from #13:0:

```
select children from #13:0
```

returns me only ids of children

```
traverse children from #13:0
```

returns me parent and children

What is correct way to fetch full children records only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
select expand(children) from #13:0
```